# Operators in C/C++/Java

Tags: java, c++, c, operators

Consider the following fragment:

```
int a,b;
a = 1;
b = 2;

c = a++++b; // does not work!! Compilation error.
c = a++*+b; // works !!
```

Help me understand this behaviour.

Comment: "Does not work" is unusably vague. It assumes there is an expected output which represents "works", and an actual output which represents "does not work", and you have failed to provide either.

Comment: What's the point?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
c = a++++b;
```

is treated as:

```
c = ((a++)++)b;
```

which is incorrect as you are trying to increment non-lvalue.

and

```
c = a++*+b;
```

is treated as:

```
c = (a++)*(+b);
```

The cause for this behaviour is: The C language lexical analyzer is [greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch).

In case 1: After the token 'a' (identifier) the lexer sees +, followed by another +, so it consumes both (as the increment operator) as part of same token. It does not make the 3rd + part of the same token as +++ is not a valid token. Similarly it groups the next two + into ++ token making it effectively same as:

```
c = ((a++)++)b;
```

which is not correct as a++ will not return a lvalue, hence you can't apply a ++ on it. Something similar to saying 5++;

But in case2: the first pair of ++ will be grouped together (as increment operator). Next the * alone will be a token as you cannot combine it with a + as *+ is not a valid token. Finally the + will a token (as unary +) effectively making your statement as:

```
c = (a++)*(+b);
```

You can override this greedy behaviour of the lexer by making use of parenthesis or whitespaces as follows:

```
c = a++ + +b;  
c = a++ * +b;
```

Answer (score 7):

This is effectively because of "[maximum munch rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch)" in C.

```
c = a++++b;
```

is parsed as `c = a++ ++ b;`, which is syntax error.

```
c = a++*+b;
```

is parsed as `c = a++ * +b;`, which is OK.

From the C99 draft, section 6.4p4 (emphasis mine):

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the next preprocessing token is the *longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token*.

Comment: Thanks Alok for giving the reference and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm). ++ has high priority than binary +.

Comment: I don't see how it could be operator precedence.

Comment: c = a++ + +b; is fine but if you remove white spaces then it turns out be an invalid lvalue error.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the problem. thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

precedance of ++ is equal to precedance of +. So we use left to right.

Answer (score 0):

The same reason why we get an error in the C++ for:

```
vector<vector<int>>;
```

The `>>` will be treated as one operator.

Comment: Good point, but is not related to OP's question.